# Binning data into user-defined bins using groupby in python polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe which contains only values between 0 and 1 for all columns (the dataframe describes data coverage for different variables). Small example:

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[0,0.5,1,1],'b':[0,0,0,1]})
>>> df
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0   │
│ 0.5 ┆ 0   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 0   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I am now only interested in counting the occurrences of no coverage (entry equal to zero), partial coverage (entry greater than zero and smaller than one), and full coverage (entry equal to one) per variable. For a single column (e.g. 'a') I came up with the following expression:

```py
>>> df.groupby(pl.when(pl.col('a')==0).then('nothing').when((pl.col('a')>0)&(pl.col('a')<1)).then('partial').otherwise('complete').alias('coverage')).count()
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ coverage ┆ count │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ u32   │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ partial  ┆ 1     │
│ nothing  ┆ 1     │
│ complete ┆ 2     │
└──────────┴───────┘
```

Now I would like to extend this solution, i.e. produce this output for multiple columns at once and aggregate it into one dataframe such that I do not have to execute the above statement on each column individually. Result should look like

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ coverage ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str      ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ nothing  ┆ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ partial  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ complete ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
└──────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Does somebody have a good recipe for this?
Mange tack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could reshape with `.melt()` + `.pivot()`

```
(
   df.melt(variable_name='columns')
     .with_columns(coverage =     
        pl.when(pl.col('value') == 0).then('nothing')
          .when(pl.col('value').is_between(0, 1, closed='none')).then('partial')
          .otherwise('complete')
     )
    .pivot('columns', 'coverage', 'columns', aggregate_function='count')
    .fill_null(0)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ coverage ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str      ┆ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ nothing  ┆ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ partial  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ complete ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
└──────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most performant way is to do what you're doing but in a loop with joins. You can also type a bit less using a `map_dict` and `fill_null` than `when`/`then`/`otherwise`.

```
lazies=None
for col in df.columns:
    temp=(
        df
            .groupby(pl.col(col).map_dict({0:'nothing',1:'complete'})
                     .fill_null('partial').alias('coverage'))
            .agg(pl.count().alias(col))
    )
    if lazies is None:
        lazies=temp.lazy()
    else:
        lazies=lazies.join(temp.lazy(), on='coverage',how='outer')
lazies.collect().with_columns(pl.all().fill_null(0))

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ coverage ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ ---      ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str      ┆ u32 ┆ u32 │
╞══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ complete ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
│ partial  ┆ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ nothing  ┆ 1   ┆ 3   │
└──────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Hi,
I do not know whether it is of importance to you, but just wanted to let you know that albeit your answer also being useful I selected https://stackoverflow.com/users/19355181/jqurious answer because I think a pure polars expression solution is quite elegant.